# lda.update(corpus) -Updating the model by incrementally training on the new corpus runs for a very long time

Tags: machine-learning, analytics, topic-modeling

I have trained my LDA model and saved it on a disk.

```
`lda_model_tfidf = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(self.corpus_tfidf, num_topics=4, id2word=dictionary, passes=1, workers=3)`
```

Method used for saving the data:

`lda_model_tfidf.save("ldamodel")`

Output after saving the model : 1)ldamodel file 2)ldamodelexpElogbeta.npy 3)ldamodel.id2wor 4)ldamodel.state

Now when I try update the model after training on the new corpus, the code runs continuously.

```
`lda.update(corpus)`
```

I need help in updating the model after training on the new corpus!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please properly format your code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Petezurich! thank you. I have formated the code.